# how to parse table's tags as pandas df

Tags: python

There is a table on this website
https://www.localeplanet.com/icu/iso3166.html

I want to parse column ID and ICU locales in this country
but for ICU locales in this country only the language code for example in first row 'ca-AD'

so far I have written following code:

```
r = requests.get("https://www.localeplanet.com/icu/iso3166.html") 
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
data = []
rows = soup.find_all('tr')
for row in rows:
    cols = row.find_all('td')
    cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
    data.append([ele for ele in cols if ele])
```

how to extract only the language code from the second column?

Comment: What is "rows" from your code  ?

Comment: @EnriqueBenitoCasado oh sorry, I have edited to question

Comment: For many countries you have more than one language code (i.e. the string for `CA` is `English (Canada) (en-CA)French (Canada) (fr-CA)`). What output do you expect in this case?

Comment: @Nicola oh, I guess I expect them to be in different row
so if Canada has more that one lang, then I will have two rows with Canada country ID, and in each row unique language code

Comment: @Nicola what I strive to do, is to have an input, to which I will pass a country ID and it will return me with its language codes as a df

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you could do to order your output and to make it ready for a `DataFrame` is using a dictionary instead of a list. I modified your code a little bit to use a dictionary:

```py
data = {}
rows = soup.find_all('tr')
for row in rows:
    cols = row.find_all('td')
    cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
    cells = [ele for ele in cols]
    if cells:
        data[cells[0]] = cells[1] # key is country code, value is string to parse

print(data)
```

which outputs:

```py
{
 'AD': 'Catalan (Andorra)\xa0(ca-AD)',
 'AE': 'Arabic (United Arab Emirates)\xa0(ar-AE)',
 'AF': 'Persian (Afghanistan)\xa0(fa-AF)Pashto (Afghanistan)\xa0(ps-AF)Uzbek (Arabic, Afghanistan)\xa0(uz-Arab-AF)',
 'AG': 'English (Antigua & Barbuda)\xa0(en-AG)',
 'AI': 'English (Anguilla)\xa0(en-AI)',
 ...
}
```

Now we have to apply a regex to parse the language codes. Every language code is contained in a couple of parenthesis, but we also have the name of the country between parenthesis before each language code. So it's possible to get all the elements in the string that are enclosed in parenthesis and just keep the elements that, in the resulting list of matched strings, have an odd index.
We need to remember that we need to remove the enclosing parenthesis for each code. The code that implements these operations is the following:

```
import re

for key, value in data.items():
    print(value)
    strings_matched = re.findall("\([^(]*\)", value)
    codes = strings_matched[1::2] # keep only elements with odd index
    codes = [x[1:-1] for x in codes] # remove opening and closing parenthesis
    data[key] = codes

print(data)
```

The final dictionary is the following and makes it simple to get the language codes starting with the country codes:

```
{'AD': ['ca-AD'],
 'AE': ['ar-AE'],
 'AF': ['fa-AF', 'ps-AF', 'uz-Arab-AF'],
 'AG': ['en-AG'],
 'AI': ['en-AI'],
 'AL': ['sq-AL'],
 'AM': ['hy-AM'],
 'AO': ['ln-AO', 'pt-AO'],
 ...
}
```